# jquery children selector issue

Tags: jquery

Hi I have  shared the code here : http://jsfiddle.net/jTAZ4/

Why am i getting the length as 0 although I can see an li with the specified class. any help is deeply appreciated.

I know this will work with find but just wondering why children selector doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `<li>` is not a direct children of that `<div>`.

[You should use `.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of `.children()`.

Comment: well i knew i had to use find but i dint know .children just searched for elements single level down

Answer (score 1):

[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) only selects direct children. Try [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.find('.jstree-leaf')` instead of `.children('.jstree-leaf')`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.find()` instead of `.children()`

```
alert($('div.round').find('.jstree-leaf').length);
```

`.children()` only searches one level deeper and skips all the elements in deeper levels.